# Obtaining comparable scores across factors from factor analysis in R

Tags: r, factor-analysis, standardization, psychometrics

I am looking for some help with factor analysis in R.

I ran a factor analysis using psych package and ended up with a four-factor model, which is fine. BUT...

I want to use the results in further analysis to :

- discuss which of the factors is the most prevalent for each respondent,
- eventually, use the factor scores in regression and/or other analyses

The scores I get are all standardized and I get it, but since the ranges of what the max and min are differ, I don't know how to proceed to compare the cases across factors.

My original data is 7-point Likert. I would like to get a similar or at least anything I can use to compare. I tried unstandardizing them using the advice from other threads, with the following code:

```
unstandardized_factor_scores<-rowMeans(data)+apply(data,1,sd)*factor_scores
```

It did shift the distribution above zero but I still have negative values, min and max differ for each factor, and the individual scores are not in the original range. Would any of you have a suggestion on what to do? All advice will be highly appreciated, thanks a lot!!!

P.S. I also tried extracting row means, but since some factor loadings are negative, the results again cannot be compared.  I also cannot do a sum of all items per factor since each factor has a different number of factors that were found as contributing to it.

Comment: what are you using the factors scores for? Factor scores are supposed to be estimates of a latent construct which you hope to measure indirectly by means of questionnaire items. Usually, it's hard to believe or expect that such a latent construct would behave as a 7-point Likert scale.

Comment: @utobi thanks for the prompt answer. Maybe I formulated the question in a too confusing way. I don't necessarily need or expect the latent constructs to behave the same way, I just need to find a way to make comparisons between these latent constructs that I have found. E.g. "which latent trait is the most pronounced for each respondent?" For now, I can say something about each latent construct separately, e.g. respondent 124. has the highest score on factor 1. But since they are not on the same "scale" I cannot say if respondent 124 is more characterized by factor 1, 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: If they are all standardized (mean=0, sd=1), then doesn't that put them on a comparable scale (or as comparable a scale as you're likely to get for variables that have no natural scale)?  For a standardized variable, the value tells you how many standard deviations the observation is above the mean.  You could use that directly.  Another option would be to convert each of them values into percentiles (or ranks).

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Isn't the value telling me how many standard deviations the observation is above the mean distribution of each respective latent construct? Let's say I have a respondents with the following standardized scores on my 4 factors:  F1 = -1.44, F2 = -1.39, F3 =-0.01, F4 = 4.79
I can say that Respodent scores high on F4 compared to scores of other respondents on F4. But can I say that F1 is the least pronounced trait for the respondent ? Can I make such comparisons across factors?

Comment: At its heart, this question isn't really about the results of factor analysis, but how to variables that are on potentially different scales.  I think my suggestion of finding the rank or percentile of the observations in the distribution might be the most fruitful avenue for investigation.